# Parameters of set method in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, reference

i have one table in cakephp database student. And i want to retrive all data from student page on webpage. We use the following statement.

$this->set('students', $this->Student->find('all'));
in controller page StudentController.php.
I cant understand why they have used 'Student' in find statement. I think 'students' is table name. But what is Student i dont know. Is it method or form name. Plz provide me some deep detail about this concept. Thanku very much

Comment: I think you haven't read a single sentence from Cakephp documentation... You should do that first and then ask questions if you still have some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer below link for better understanding:

if you are using cakephp version 2.x

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

if you are using cakephp version 3.x

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

you will definitely get much more idea.

thanks:)